# Google test using C++11/14, how to fix the invalid POSIX Extended error

Tags: c++, regex, googletest

I am using gtest to do unit test and trying to use the function `MatchesRegex`to match the pattern a string contains multiple substrings using look around. e.g

Verifying the statement `The team members are Tom, Jerry and a Terminator` contains all three keywords `Tom`, `Jerry` and `Term`

```
std::string target = "The team members are Tom, Jerry and a Terminator";
EXPECT_THAT(target, MatchesRegex("(?=.*(Tom))(?=.*(Jerry))(?=.*(Term))"));
```

But I am getting an error

```
Regular expression "((?=.*(Tom))(?=.*(Jerry))(?=.*(Term)))" is not a valid POSIX Extended regular expression.
```

Any suggestion to fix the regexp?

The test code can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:81,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:81,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:81,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:81,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cgmock/gmock.h%3E%0A%0ATEST(RegexTest,+Simple_Regex_Matcher)+%7B%0A++std::string+target+%3D+%22The+team+members+are+Tom,+Jerry+and+a+Terminator%22%3B%0A++EXPECT_THAT(target,+testing::MatchesRegex(%22(%3F%3D.*(Tom))(%3F%3D.*(Jerry))(%3F%3D.*(Term))%22))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char*argv%5B%5D)%7B%0A++++testing::InitGoogleTest(%26argc,+argv)%3B%0A++++return+RUN_ALL_TESTS()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.780856132137416,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%270%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:googletest,ver:%27110%27)),options:%27-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:24.115414490010533,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:31.103729377852066,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX regular expressions in C++ are very limited. Fortunately, you may combine expectations logically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using testing::AllOf;
using testing::MatchesRegex;

TEST(RegexTest, Simple_Regex_Matcher) {
  std::string target = "The team members are Tom, Jerry and a Terminator";
  EXPECT_THAT(target, AllOf(MatchesRegex(".*Tom.*"), MatchesRegex(".*Jerry.*"), MatchesRegex(".*Term.*")));
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Output:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from RegexTest
[ RUN      ] RegexTest.Simple_Regex_Matcher
[       OK ] RegexTest.Simple_Regex_Matcher (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from RegexTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know what might be the reason ppl giving those down votes?

Comment: I do not know. Fortunately I have been able to post the answer before the question closed.

Answer (score 2):

I marked [@273k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70690538/2185248)'s answer as the accepted answer. But in my final solution, I use something like

```
EXPECT_THAT(target, AllOf(HasSubstr("Tom"), HasSubstr("Jerry"), HasSubstr("Term")));
```

Which is inspired by [@273k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70690538/2185248)'s answer. Regexp is much shorter and slow but AllOf+HasSubstr has better readablility.